# From a Roman Catholic view, after God creates a soul, does He let the soul to choose if they want to enter a body? Can a soul refuse to be embodied?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-man, original-sin, free-will, souls

The Catholic Catechism says this:

366 The Church teaches that every spiritual soul is created immediately by God - it is not "produced" by the parents - and also that it is immortal: it does not perish when it separates from the body at death, and it will be reunited with the body at the final Resurrection.

In my previous question, it was established that God creates the soul and then, some time after, infuses the soul into a human embryo. In that moment between creation and infusion, does God give the soul the chance to refuse being ensouled in a body? Can the soul make a free will choice not to take on a body? Or does God force each soul to become embodied against their will? The reason a soul might not want to be infused into a body is to avoid the stain of original sin. A soul might not want to take on human nature and the subsequent taint of original sin and risk damnation. If the soul is forced to take on original sin against their will, how can a just and loving God threaten punishment?

Comment: can you link to your previous question? also scope this to a specific denomination since answers will vary based on that.

Comment: A human soul without a human nature is not a human soul at all. This is a contradiction in terms. Agreed on the denomination-specific thing. A Catholic, for instance, would not have even answered the prior question the way it apparently was answered.

Comment: Yea this needs more focus. What denomination are you referring too?

Comment: I'm not sure how to link to my previous question.

Comment: Is this the previous question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89263/when-god-creates-each-individual-soul-is-it-without-original-sin-at-that-moment

Comment: To link to another question simply click and drag over the https:// details at the top of the question and copy and paste it into your document.

Answer (score 1):

## Creation & infusion one simultaneous act

No, because God creates the soul immediately and unites it immediately to the matter when the matter is properly disposed.

The soul is the [substantial form](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/49310/49461) of a human, and the form+matter of something cannot exist apart from one another.

<sup>Even death, when the soul separates from the body (i.e., no longer animates it), does not sever the relation the body and soul have to one another; hence why our bodies will resurrect on the last day.</sup>

St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Summa contra gentiles* ch. 89](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles2.htm#89), n. 17 (cf. [*Compendium Theologiæ* ch. 95](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Compendium.htm#95) on the soul's "immediate creation by God"):

> when the body is actually human, as being perfected by the human soul, it neither precedes nor follows the soul, but is **simultaneous** with it.
> <sub>Cum vero est humanum actu, quasi per animam humanam perfectum, non est prius neque posterius anima, sed **simul** cum ea.</sub>

This truth seems implicitly contained in Pope Pius IX's declaration of the dogma of the Immaculate Conception, [*Ineffabilis Deus*](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius09/p9ineff.htm), where he says:

> the most Blessed Virgin Mary, in the first instance of her conception (*primo instanti suæ conceptionis*)

He does not say "her soul's" nor "her body's" but "*her* [body+soul composite] conception", i.e., the conception of her *person*.

<sup>cf. "[Could 'The human soul is created at the moment of conception.' be defined as dogma?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68504/1787)"</sup>

The creation of the soul and its infusion is one instantaneous act. We can distinguish them in our minds (logical distinction), but they can't exist separately in reality. A human soul with no relation to a human body makes no sense because the soul is the substantial form of the body.

## Pre-existentianism

Pre-existentianism is the heresy that human souls exist before the creation of their corresponding bodies. It was condemned in the Canons against Origen ([Denzinger 20](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n200)3):

> 1. If anyone says or holds that the souls of men pre-existed, as if they were formerly minds and holy powers, but having received a surfeit of beholding the Divinity, and having turned towards the worse, and on this account having shuddered (*apopsycheisas*) at the love of God, in consequence being called souls (*psychae*) and being sent down into bodies for the sake of punishment, let him be anathema.

and the Council of Braga against the Priscillianists ([Denzinger 2](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n200)36):

> 6. If anyone says that human souls first sinned in the heavenly habitation and in view of this were hurled down into human bodies on earth, as Priscillian has affirmed, let him be anathema.

<sup>source: Ludwig Ott, *[Fundamentals of Catholic Dogma](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7262)*, bk. 2, § 15. The Origin of Individual Human Souls, p. 99</sup>

Comment: But you are saying that the creation of the soul and the infusion of the soul into a body are 2 separate acts--whether or not they happen simultaneously. One of those acts could occur without the other happening--the soul could be created and not infused into a body. You are also saying that God does not give the soul the free will choice to decide whether they want to be infused into a body. Why doesn't God give us the chance to choose, as souls, whether we want to be infused into a body tainted with original sin?

Comment: See [what I added](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/89298/revisions) to my answer.

Comment: From The Catholic Herald: "The Church, however, does not specifically define when ensoulment takes place. However, we rightly believe that Almighty God infuses the soul into the body when in accord with His will that creation is a person: for most of us, that would be at conception, but for identical twins or others, this would be after the initially fertilized single ovum divides." According to this, the Church has no teaching about whether the creation of the soul and embodiment are simultaneous. Where is that teaching in the Catechism?

Comment: That journalist seems to mean that the Church has not [_de fide_](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50429/1787) defined the truth, but that doesn't mean "the Church has no teaching about whether the creation of the soul and embodiment are simultaneous". Have you seen my question: "[Could 'The human soul is created at the moment of conception.' be defined as dogma?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68504/1787)"?

Comment: It's not defined as dogma--full stop. Probabalism tells us we can come to our own conclusions based on our understanding of reputable authorities. So, prior to the soul being embodied, does God give them a choice whether they want to be ensoulded? Could a soul refuse to be embodied?

Comment: Pre-existentianism is condemned _de fide_. How is what you're suggesting different from pre-existentianism?

Comment: Where is condemned de fide? There's never been a ex cathedra pronouncement--and it is likely that the condemnation of Origen was based on a misunderstanding. Pope Benedict calls him a "master of faith" https://www.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/audiences/2007/documents/hf_ben-xvi_aud_20070425.html

Comment: "_Where is condemned de fide?_" In the two anathemas in my answer.

Comment: Since the Church has not declared when a soul is infused into a body, there can't be a de fide pronouncement against all forms of pre-existentianism. Some forms thought to be promoted by Origen (but probably not) were condemned, but not all possible forms. A difficulty in discussing Catholic issues, I've noticed, is that you can list the theologians, pronouncements, and saints which agree with you, and I can list the theologians, pronouncements, and saints which agree with me--which list points to the truth when there is no official, final, ex cathedra announcement on the issue?

Comment: I ask again: How is what you're suggesting different from pre-existentianism? Also, the Church has defined the human soul as "the form of the human body" ([Council of Vienne](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/42289/1787)).

Comment: 1974 Declaration on Procured Abortion: “This declaration expressly leaves aside the question of the moment when the spiritual soul is infused. There is not a unanimous tradition on this point and authors are as yet in disagreement. For some it dates from the first instant; for others it could not at least precede nidation [implantation in the uterus]." This says that there are Catholics in good standing who believe the soul pre-exists the embryo and is implanted later--like Aquinas. Is that what you mean by pre-existentianism? In which case, that's what the Church teaches.

Comment: @Stuart "_the soul pre-exists the embryo_" makes no sense, like saying "the soul that pre-exists the toddler", "…the adult", etc.; an embryo is a human being at an early stage of development. How could a human's soul pre-exist the human? A human is a body+soul.